# What is a commonly available wood that will be strong enough for this thin piece?

Tags: wood, strength

I am trying to make a center console for my car.  The piece in question looks like this:
[image]

You can see that one side of the smaller cupholder hole was broken just by the activity of handling the piece and using the hole saw.  This is 3/8" OSB and I would really like something half the thickness.  What kind of wood could I buy that could make this piece, be ~5mm thick, and be reasonably strong?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. That's awfully close to the edge there, but the thing is the problem occurred during the process — this is the kind of thing where ideally you cut the holes, *then* trim close. Half this thickness and still be strong enough to withstand the rigours of use seems like a stretch for wood, or a wood product, at the thickness you're hoping. You might want to consider making this from polycarbonate, or sheet metal, or maybe fibreglass.

Comment: Smoked lexan (or perspex, if your pond orientation is a little different) all day, every day. Just know that drill bits generally and hole saws particularly don’t get on with lexan if you assume it behaves like wood. A drill with a clutch or a drill press with clamps will improve your life.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Plywood, particularly high-grade plywood, will be a lot stronger than OSB.

But as Graphus said, you are stretching what wood will do.

Cutting the hole first, *then* cutting the straight edge (very, very, carefully - perhaps with a router) will certainly help (hole saws are not really precision tools and will often exert pressure on the side of the hole).

Mixing a very fluid epoxy mix, and then getting it to soak into the area which will be very thin when you have cut the edge will help (build a suitable dam with plasticine or similar to give it a good chance to soak in).

Finally, does this breakage actually matter?  I presume the cupholder has a metal rim which will cover the broken wood.